# Getting 400 Bad Request Error When Making POST Request to obtain JWT Token Using HttpService in NestJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs, nestjs

I'm developing a NestJS application where I need to obtain a JWT token by making a **POST request**. I'm utilizing the `HttpService` from the `@nestjs/common` library. However, I consistently encounter a **400 Bad Request error**.

Here's the code using HttpService to get JWT token:

```
import {
  HttpService,
  InternalServerErrorException,
} from "@nestjs/common";


export class JwtService {
 constructor(private httpService: HttpService, private cache: CacheService) {}
private getAuthToken(): Observable<OAuth> {
    const url = 'endpoint_url';
    const body = JSON.stringify({
      "client_id": 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      "client_secret": 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    });

    const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
    return this.callAPI(url, body, headers);
  }

private callAPI(
    url: string,
    body,
    headers: { [key: string]: string }
  ): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpService.post(url, body, headers).pipe(
          map((result: AxiosResponse<any>) => result.data),
          tap((result: any) => {
            const { access_token } = result; // eslint-disable-line
            this.cache
              .set("authToken", access_token, {
                ttl: env.SECONDS_TO_EXPIRE,
              })
              .subscribe();
          }),
          catchError((err: any) => {
            return throwError(
              new InternalServerErrorException(err.message, "Auth Service")
            );
          })
        );
      })
  }
}
}
```

Here's what I've already tried:

1. **Other APIs**: I tested the same code with other APIs, and it worked flawlessly. The issue seems specific to the JWT token API.
2. **Postman Success**: When I manually send the request using Postman (same URL, body, and headers), I successfully receive the token.
3. **Body Format**: I attempted using a plain object for the request body instead of a JSON object, but the error persists.
4. **Fetch API**: I also experimented with the `fetch()` API, and it returned the expected response (code snippet below).

Sample code using fetch api:

```
const req = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        client_id: XXXXXXXXXX,
        client_secret: XXXXXXXXXXX,
        grant_type: XXXXXXXXXXX,
      }),
    };
    fetch('jwt_token_endpoint', req)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.logger.log(`Success retrieving jwt token`);
        console.log(data);
        this.jwtSubject.next(`${data.token}`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.logger.error(`Error retrieving jwt token: ${error}`);
      });
```

I am looking for an assistance to resolve the error and get the token successfully.

Comment: try this: don't `JSON.stringify(` the `body`

Comment: Tried with just an body object (without JSON.stringify). Still getting the same error.

Comment: check the requests in browser developer tools - i.e. look at the request headers and the request body and compare the details of the request what works (fetch) with what doesn't (i.e. nestjs with uses axios which is just XMLHttpRequest)